# Setting z-index of `$.mobile.loading`

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery's `$.mobile.loading` function in the following function:

```
 function showLoading(msg) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
    text: msg,
    textVisible: true,
    theme: 'b',
    html: ""
        });
}, 1);
```

Sometimes the loader is in the background because a div is on top of it. How can I set the `z-index` to really high, or do something else to make sure it's always on top of everything?

Comment: Why not just `z-index: 9999` or something?

Comment: @Itay How can I set the `z-index` of this element. That's what I'm having trouble doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the `.ui-loader` class?

Put this on your CSS file:

```
.ui-loader {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the .css function to change it, for example :

```
$("#foo").css('z-index','2000');
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/css/)